# Powershell wmi to check and see if a disk is in ONLINE status?

Tags: powershell, wmi, disk

Powershell wmi to check and see if a disk is in ONLINE status? I could not find one online.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "online"? If the disk has been initialized and is shown as online in `diskmgmt.msc`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are talking about the Operational Status property for "Online". Newer operating systems should have the WMI Class in MSFT_Disk in the root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage Namespace. The older Win32_Disk in root/cimv2 won't have it.

```
gcim MSFT_Disk -Namespace root/Microsoft/Windows/Storage | select FriendlyName,GUID,OperationalStatus
```